# Memory usage of a single process with psutil in python (in byte)

Tags: memory, process, psutil

How to get the amount of memory which has been used by a single process in windows platform with psutil library? (I dont want to have the percentage , I want to know the amount in bytes)

We can use:

```
psutil.virtual_memory().used
```

To find the memory usage of the whole OS in bytes, but how about each single process?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call [`memory_info_ex`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.memory_info_ex):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> p = psutil.Process()
>>> p.name()
'python.exe'

>>> _ = p.memory_info_ex()
>>> _.wset, _.pagefile
(11665408, 8499200)
```

The [working set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc441804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) includes pages that are shared or shareable by other processes, so in the above example it's actually larger than the paging file commit charge.

There's also a simpler `memory_info` method. This returns `rss` and `vms`, which correspond to `wset` and `pagefile`.

```
>>> p.memory_info()
pmem(rss=11767808, vms=8589312)
```

---

For another example, let's map some shared memory.

```
>>> import mmap
>>> m = mmap.mmap(-1, 10000000)
>>> p.memory_info()            
pmem(rss=11792384, vms=8609792)
```

The mapped pages get demand-zero faulted into the working set.

```
>>> for i in range(0, len(m), 4096): m[i] = 0xaa
...
>>> p.memory_info()                             
pmem(rss=21807104, vms=8581120)
```

A private copy incurs a paging file commit charge:

```
>>> s = m[:]
>>> p.memory_info()
pmem(rss=31830016, vms=18604032)
```